# Does this $p$-series have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac {1}{i^2}$

I was reading on harmonic numbers and read that there is no closed-form and this leads me to wonder if this series has one. I spent a good portion of today deriving the closed form of a few different series using geometry and a few algebraic manipulations, but couldn't quite figure this one out.

One of these series was

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$

as I thought this may help. Am I on the right track if it does exist?

Comment: It is $\zeta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}6$, and it can be calculated via Fourier series.

Comment: The *finite* sum? No, it (essentially) doesn't.